# Cycles issue - Edges of the mesh show on some parts of model

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, artifacts

I have a number of rocks generated with geometry nodes, then sculpted. The issue is that the edges look split at certain parts of the model, it is almost like the wireframe shows up at some places.

The mesh itself seems fine, there are no open edges, all vertices are merged. There is no UV map on the model and all modifiers have been applied. Shader is just a basic principled BSDF with nothing connected into it.

Went through all the object data properties, there is nothing out of ordinary.

Also worth noting, if i remesh with voxel or quad remesh, the artifacts are still present.

Artifacts only show in Cycles, in EEVEE it renders properly.

Blender version 4.0.0

[image]

UPDATE
It seems like, artifact only shows up at places where two meshes are close together, so it must be a lighting issue related to GI shadows.
If I move the rock away from all other models, it renders properly

Answer (score 0):

Alright, in case someone comes across the same issue:

The model is for a project where the position of the objects comes from QGIS, geolocated on a terrain model. Because of the surveyed terrain is quite large (10km x 10km) the rocks are positioned pretty far away from the origin (around 5000m).
If I move them back to origin, all lighting artifacts disappear.
It messes with the workflow, but at least solves the problem.